# iOS branch +clicked_branch_link is FALSE

Tags: ios, swift, branch.io

when I tap on deep link. If app is running on the background, branch gets callback and the value of +clicked_branch_link is TRUE But when app is not running then app launches properly and +clicked_branch_link is FALSE, instead +clicked_branch_link must be true.

"+clicked_branch_link": 0, "+is_first_session": 1

```
    func setupBranchLinkHandling(_ launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) {
    

    Branch.getInstance().initSession(launchOptions: launchOptions) { [weak self] (params, error) in
        guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
        // do stuff with deep link data (nav to page, display content, etc)
        print(params as? [String: AnyObject] ?? {})
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question to state your problem more clearly.

Comment: @mag_zbc when I tap on deep link. If app is running on the background, branch gets callback and the value of +clicked_branch_link is TRUE But when app is not running then app launches properly and +clicked_branch_link is FALSE, instead +clicked_branch_link must be true